# Failed to import ndb Key class method : from_old_key in Eclipse-PyDev

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, importerror, app-engine-ndb

I tried to use in Eclipse / PyDev :

```
from google.appengine.ext import db, ndb

ndb_key = ndb.Key.from_old_key(db_entity.key())  # but the import gives an error
```

The Pydev error : undefined variable from import : from_old_key

But when I deploy the app (including the import error), it works fine.

My temp solution :

```
import google.appengine.ext.ndb.key as ndbkey

ndb_key = ndbkey.Key.from_old_key(db_entity.key())
```

Comment: Maybe it's a PyDev error?  Try another editor.